# How to run macro on different files?

Tags: excel, vba

So I am pretty new to macro. I have a program saved on an excel spreadsheet, but I do not want to keep opening this file each time to have the code run on other excel spreadsheets, how can I just open an excel file and have the Macro run on it without opening the original excel file with the original code?
The code is:

```
Sub WHENTECH()

    LastRow = Cells(row.count, "F").End(xlUp).row

    For lRow = 1 To LastRow
        Select Case Range("D" & lRow).value
        Case "LN"
            Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow) / 10

        Case "NG"
            Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow) / 10

        Case Else
            Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow)

        End Select
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Sorry, this is my first post on Stack Overflow and I am unsure how to add the code block on here properly.

Comment: have a quick search for "personal.xlsb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the macro in the "Personal" macro workbook.

This you can find if you go to Windows : UnHide .

Then you can use the vba editor to copy it or duplicate it in that workbook which means it will be available to any workbook you have open.  This does mean you have to write the macros to address the file by name...

When you record a macro - you are also given an option as to where you want it stored either the current workbook or the Personal one.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the excel files in the same directory?

If so, use this-

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'your code here-

        LastRow = Cells(row.count, "F").End(xlUp).row

        For lRow = 1 To LastRow
            Select Case Range("D" & lRow).value
            Case "LN"
                Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow) / 10

            Case "NG"
                Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow) / 10

            Case Else
                Range("F" & lRow) = Range("F" & lRow)

            End Select
        Next lRow

        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same file. The file is just titled WHENTECH. Where would i put the file name?